# Get user name/id in the web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web Api in C#. I need user id/name in the api controller function when ever the user tries to access the api.

I tried `Request.Principle` and `Http.Context.User`  but in both the identity.Name is comming as null. Can you please tell how can I get the username in the Api.

Comment: [This blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter#Authorization) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string _userName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in you class to get the user Id

```
var userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```